# running 5 python programs together via shell scripting

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have 5 python programs and i want to run them all simultaneously./concurrently

lets say i have these programs

```
python1.py
python2.py
python3.py
python4.py
python5.py
```

How can a shell script run them all together? if i just put 5 commands like this

```
all.sh
 python python1.py
 python python2.py
 python python3.py
 python python4.py
 python python5.py
```

will they work all together?

Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
python python1.py &
python python2.py &
python python3.py &
python python4.py &
python python5.py &

wait # this will wait for all of them to finish
```

Comment: great. what does the & symbol do?

Comment: Starts a job in the background.

Comment: just to make sure: all of them will run in a parallel way?